# d3.js multi-level nesting and multi line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a multi line graph, using the data from a multi-level nesting.
I am using d3.v3

The data looks like this ( except couple of thousands of line):

```
postnr,verd,date 
101,64900000,1.7.2016
220,25900000,1.7.2016
101,27900000,1.6.2016
220,34900000,1.6.2016
105,18000000,1.6.2016
105,33500000,1.5.2016
105,64900000,1.5.2016
220,24800000,1.5.2016
101,32200000,1.4.2016
```

my code:

```js
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 100
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var lineVerd = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.verd);
  });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.date;})
    .key(function(d) {return d.postnr; }) // HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    .rollup(function(d) {
      return d3.mean(d, function(g) {
        return g.verd;
      });
    }).entries(data);

  // rename the variables back
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.key);
    d.verd = d.values;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  // y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.values; })]);
  //  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.values; }));
  y.domain([20000000, 50000000]);


  //     Add the lineVerd path.
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", lineVerd(data));

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

});
```

What I am trying to do is create a multi-line graph using the postnr from the multi level nesting as groups.

I know the data coming from the nesting is good. I just can't draw the lines.